# C++ Syntax to call a member function using it's function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

The example below uses a function pointer to a member function of the class Blah. The syntax of the function pointer is clear to me. However when calling I had to put brackets around `this->*funcPtr` and I am not sure why this is required. I guess it is related to the way how C++ evaluates the expression. The compiler used is VS 2008.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Blah {

    void myMethod(int i, int k) {
        cout << "Hi from myMethod. Arguments: " << i << " " << k << endl;
    }

    typedef void (Blah::*blahFuncPtr)(int, int);

    void travelSomething(blahFuncPtr funcPtr) {
        (this->*funcPtr)(1, 2);
        // w/o the brackets I get C2064 in VS 2008
        // this->*funcPtr(1, 2);
    }
};

int main() {
    Blah blah;
    blah.travelSomething(&Blah::myMethod);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.6

Comment: Ok, maybe a macro would be a good idea. But that still doesn't answer my question. I would like to know why..

Comment: Uh and how would one define a macro for pointers to function which take arguments using variadic macros for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function call operator `()` takes higher precendence than the 'pointer to member' operator `->*`.

See, for example, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).